# How to get PostgreSQL range types via jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Is there right way to get range types?

Or parse as String, and wait for native support...

For example **tsrange**:

```
["2010-01-01 14:00:00","2010-01-01 15:00:00"]
```

[PG Range tupes - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/rangetypes.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/rangetypes.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use range functions in your query to create individual date columns.

```
select lower(some_range) as start, upper(some_range) as end ...
```

Then you can use ResultSet's getDate() method on the resulting columns.